# As much as Varga tried to hide it, neither did he

Tags: tag-questions

> Now consider the final scene of the Fargo season finale, in which Department of Homeland Security Agent Gloria Burgle sits in front of V.M. Varga. Several years have passed since the two last crossed each other’s paths, but Gloria never forgot the one that got away. **As much as Varga tried to hide it, neither did he**. He may have needed a refresher, but the main reason he played dumb was to take the alpha role and show her he didn’t even think about her after the events in Minnesota.

Source: https://www.outkickthecoverage.com/review-fargo-year-3-finale/

I am not sure how to understand the passage in bold.

1. The first part "As much as Varga tried to hide it". Does it mean that Varga tries to hide the mentioned fact as well as Gloria Burgle does not hide it?
2. In what sense is the question tag used here? I am familiar with the function of the question tag (for example: *'They aren't very good at sports.' 'Neither are we.'*), but here there are two subjects: "they" and "we." In my sentence, there is just one subject, Varga.

Comment: *Neither did we* is not a question tag--it's an ordinary assertion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no knowledge of the context, but it appears that

- Gloria and Varga had some sort of romantic relationship when their paths crossed earlier.
- Gloria could not *forget the one who got away*—presumably Varga.
- *Neither did he*: Varga also could not *forget the one who got away*—presumably Gloria.
- Varga attempts to conceal his inability to forget Gloria—he sought to *take the alpha role and show he didn't even think about her* after their previous encounter.